# Quotient Space Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

Why is $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ a Hausdorff space, if we assume that $\mathbb{R}$ has the canonical topology, and $\mathbb{Z}$ the induced subspacetopology?

More generally, which requirements for a topologal space $S$ ans it's subspace $U$ allow to conclude that $S/U$ is hausdorff?

Comment: I am wondering where you have encountered the notation $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, because it is usually *not* an incidence of the topological notation $S/U$. *Instead* it is an incidence of the group theory notation $G/N$ where $G$ is a (topological) group and $N$ is a (closed) normal subgroup. The topological quotient and the group theoretic quotient are different kinds of quotients.

Comment: This was postulated as the definition of the circle group. So it's clear if we identify it with $\{z \in \mathbb{C} |  1 = |z| \}$ that it's hausdorff but the background of my question was how to compute this from the properties of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fact: Let $X$ be a $T_3$ space (regular and $T_1$) and $A$ a subspace of $ X$, then $X{/}A$ in the quotient topology is Hausdorff iff $A$ is closed.

This assumes the usual quotient of modding out by a subspace: identifying that set to a point, so the equivalence classes of $X{/}A$ are $\{A\} \cup \{\{x\}: x \notin A\}$

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, this quotient is hausdorff iff the relation is closed.
Note that the quotient $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is in this case (the case where it defines the circle group $S^1$) a group theoretical quotient. The relation is thus
$$\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid a-b \in \mathbb{Z}\} = f^{-1}(\mathbb{Z})$$
where
$$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: (a,b) \mapsto a-b$$
Now, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, and $f$ is continuous (as $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is a topological group), $f^{-1}(\mathbb{Z})$ must be closed as well.

In general we have: if $X$ is a topological group that is hausdorff, and $Y$ is a closed normal subgroup, then $X/Y$ is hausdorff

Comment: I think he means identifing $\mathbb{Z}$ to a point, so a very different quotient.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Why do you think that? $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is not the notation for that. He also says in the comments that he is talking about the circle group (which is the quotient I'm working with)

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is ambiguous: it could be a group quotient (in which case you're quite right), or a purely topological quotient, and then this is an interesting quotient space (it's not first countable but it is sequential). I didn't read the comments till later, and the question alone should be enough (or else edit it based on the comments). The final sentence reeked of topology, not groups.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I have never seen the notation being used for the space you mention (I do know the space, it is a classical counterexample). Every source I have read uses $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ for the topological group quotient (ie the circle group $S^1$). Can you point me to a source that uses the notation like you interpreted it?

Comment: Engelking General Topology IIRC.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks, I'll be more carefull with the notation in the future. It is difficult to edit the question as it seems that the OP himself wasn't aware of the fact that he was talking about topological groups (and respective quotient). I will point it out in my answer tough.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z \cong (S^1,\tau)$, where $\tau$ is the subspace topology. This is the quickest way I can think of to see the result. On the other hand, one can use the fact that if $\sim$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$, then the quotient is hausdorff.

Comment: But how to see it with the latter criterion? This means to show that $\{(a, b) | a -b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is closed...

Comment: Show that the complement is open. Suppose that $(x,y) \in \mathrm{complement}$. Then $x-y \notin \mathbb Z$, so take the floor and ceiling of it, pick the minimum distance and build a suitably small box around $(x,y)$.

Comment: @KarlPeter see my answer for a more general way

Comment: Yes, I like Jens' method a lot more, it is very elegant, although maybe slightly harder to see initially, +1

Comment: I think he means identifing $\mathbb{Z}$ to a point, so a very different quotient.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma why do you think this? In this case the result is immediate, since the integers are closed in the reals.

Comment: He also wants to mod out by a subspace $U$, plus he does not mention groups in his question either. So I assume he meant the standard topology way. In the group case, also the closedness of the subgroup will be necessary and sufficient as @JensRenders already observed.